# (HTML/CSS) How To Make <audio> Tag Follow the Page?

Tags: html, css

I've tried this:

```
<div class="music8">
  <audio controls> 
  <source src="http://mcclures.tech/ect/song.mp3">
  <source src="http://mcclures.tech/ect/shatterme.mp3">
  </audio>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.music8 {
position: fixed
bottom: 0
}
```

Doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to close your CSS properties with a semi-colon. i.e. position: fixed;

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing some endings to your css statements after you state an elements attribute in css you end it with a semi-colon.  Second it is best practice to specify a left or right along with your bottom position. So it would look something like the following:

Here is a fiddle to show you [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/e1onLx5n/)

```
.music8 {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to define multiple mp3 file for one audio player. you can not do it. you will have to define one src for at a time for audio elements and if you want to change it then fetch the file path from somewhere like array and change the src by jabascript or jquery.

do something like this-- and give one src at a time.

```
<audio controls> 
<source src="http://mcclures.tech/ect/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```